# Help me with decoherence

Tags: quantum-interpretations, unitarity, decoherence

Recently I’ve been trying to make sense of decoherence, and my major concern is greatly formulated by a passage on the wikipedia page:

“Decoherence can be viewed as the loss of information from a system into the environment (often modeled as a heat bath),[4] since every system is loosely coupled with the energetic state of its surroundings. Viewed in isolation, the system's dynamics are non-unitary (although the combined system plus environment evolves in a unitary fashion).[5] Thus the dynamics of the system alone are irreversible”. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence)

How can it - evolving in a unitary fashion - make sense? Like, - assume we have a laboratory with an apparatus inside it measuring some quantum stuff. The result of the measurement is probabilistic, okay. On the other hand, the evolution of the laboratory as a whole is reversible. How can it be, as it would immediately raise contradictions: just wind the clocks this way and the other way, and, sooner or later, we will get results that don’t match each other?

I believe I clearly misinterpret things. A clarification will be of great help to me!

P.S. I’m quite aware that decoherence is loved and majorly used by followers of Everett’s interpretations. However, without interpretation, decoherence alone does not solve the measurement problem, - what it does is leaving the density matrix in a diagonal form. So, as it appears, some sort of old good Copenhagen should be compatible with decoherence too. So, how can a Copenhagian respond to reversibility of dynamics I asked above?

Comment: These do not answer your question about unitary evolution, but they may help. [Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why](https://www.facebook.com/veritasium/videos/parallel-worlds-probably-exist-heres-why/339179977597625/) from Veritasium, and [Sean Carroll explains: what is the many-worlds interpretation?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_xqNDII--Q)

Comment: @mmesser314 Thanks for your links. However, I’m looking for answers from Copenhagen’s perspective. I guess none of my concerns are valid under MWI, so this makes my question void.

Comment: The Copenhagen interpretation explicitly breaks unitarity upon measurement: it has explicitly separate rules for evolution when a system is not being measured (the Schrodinger euqation, unitary evolution) vs when it is being measured (collapse - non unitary). Of course, when and how exactly a collapsing "measurement" happens is ill-defined in copenhagen.

You can still study decoherence with copenhagen - just don't make the mistake of treating a system with you inside it as a quantum system (many worlds: yes, copenhagen: no). Think instead about a small open system, with no observers around.